# Add Product (Record) Not Working on Android Fragment

Tags: java, android

I need some help regards to my add function in Android Fragment. I have no idea where I have done wrong... So sorry for my limited knowledge on Java...

When I click the submit button, nothing is happened...I think something wrong starting at the onResponse method..

These function suppose to add record that I have key-in which are the name, price, & descriptions into the database, and if the record successfully added it will alert the user "Product Successfully Added" else it will inform the user failed to add record.

The code working well on the activity page (I copy the code from my register account activity), but not working when I move it to the fragment page.

This is AddFragment.java

```
package ezms.ezms;


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class AddFragment extends Fragment {


    public AddFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    EditText pName, pPrice, pDesc;
    Button btn_addProduct;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false);

        pName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.pName);
        pPrice = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.pPrice);
        pDesc = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.pDesc);
        btn_addProduct = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_addProduct);

        btn_addProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String name = pName.getText().toString();
                final String price = pPrice.getText().toString();
                final String desc = pDesc.getText().toString();

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if (success) {
                                AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddFragment.this.getActivity());
                                myAlertDialog.setMessage("New Product Successfully Added.");
                                myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("GOT IT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                            Toast.makeText(AddFragment.this.getActivity(), "New Product Successfully Added.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                });
                                myAlertDialog.show();

                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddFragment.this.getActivity());
                                builder.setMessage("Failed to Add Product.")
                                        .setNegativeButton("RETRY", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                AddProductRequest AddProductRequest = new AddProductRequest(name, price, desc, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(AddFragment.this.getActivity());
                queue.add(AddProductRequest);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

This is AddProductRequest.java

```
package ezms.ezms;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class AddProductRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String ADD_REQUEST_URL = "http://www.pohqw.com/projects/myapp/add_product.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    // Constructor of this class
    public AddProductRequest(String name, String price, String desc, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, ADD_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name", name);
        params.put("price", price);
        params.put("desc", desc);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

This is the error message shown at my Android Studio..

```
05-09 13:12:47.004 10674-12581/? I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:1
05-09 13:12:47.004 10674-12581/? I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:2500
05-09 13:12:47.004 10674-12581/? I/System.out: Close in OkHttp:0
05-09 13:12:47.004 10674-12581/? I/System.out: [CDS]close[38156]
05-09 13:12:47.004 10674-12581/? D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=www.pohqw.com; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
05-09 13:12:47.005 10674-12581/? D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
05-09 13:12:47.005 10674-12581/? D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=www.pohqw.com; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
05-09 13:12:47.005 10674-12581/? D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
05-09 13:12:47.007 10674-12581/? D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: www.pohqw.com get result from proxy >>
05-09 13:12:47.007 10674-12581/? I/System.out: propertyValue:true
05-09 13:12:47.008 10674-12581/? I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:2500
05-09 13:12:47.009 10674-12581/? I/System.out: [socket][5] connection www.pohqw.com/202.75.56.237:80;LocalPort=58216(2500)
05-09 13:12:47.009 10674-12581/? I/System.out: [CDS]connect[www.pohqw.com/202.75.56.237:80] tm:2
05-09 13:12:47.010 10674-12581/? D/Posix: [Posix_connect Debug]Process ezms.ezms :80 
05-09 13:12:47.066 10674-12581/? I/System.out: [socket][/192.168.1.34:58216] connected
05-09 13:12:47.067 10674-12581/? I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
05-09 13:12:47.067 10674-12581/? I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
05-09 13:12:47.385 10674-10674/? W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
05-09 13:12:47.385 10674-10674/? W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
05-09 13:12:47.385 10674-10674/? W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
05-09 13:12:47.385 10674-10674/? W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
05-09 13:12:47.385 10674-10674/? W/System.err:     at ezms.ezms.AddFragment$1$1.onResponse(AddFragment.java:59)
05-09 13:12:47.385 10674-10674/? W/System.err:     at ezms.ezms.AddFragment$1$1.onResponse(AddFragment.java:55)
05-09 13:12:47.385 10674-10674/? W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
05-09 13:12:47.385 10674-10674/? W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
05-09 13:12:47.385 10674-10674/? W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
05-09 13:12:47.385 10674-10674/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
05-09 13:12:47.385 10674-10674/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
05-09 13:12:47.385 10674-10674/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
05-09 13:12:47.385 10674-10674/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546)
05-09 13:12:47.385 10674-10674/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-09 13:12:47.385 10674-10674/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-09 13:12:47.385 10674-10674/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
05-09 13:12:47.385 10674-10674/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
```

Comment: could u explain more on what's not working?

Comment: I think something wrong happened starting at the "onResponse method"...When I click the button to submit my record, nothing happened, it suppose to alert user whether the record successfully added or not...

Comment: do you get error on Logcat?

Comment: So the AlertDialog isn't showing? What about the `e.printStackTrace();`? Any errors in the logcat?

Comment: I have added the logcat...

Comment: @Poh apparently your response is not in JSON format, you get exception on parsing it

Comment: @Poh try Log.v(response) to see the content of it

Comment: You seem to be getting HTML back, not JSON

Comment: Thank you very much guys, I have solved it, the error happening on my php file. Really appreciated for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, when I tried your URL POST, I got this:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /home/pohqw/public_html/projects/myapp/add_product.php on line 9
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /home/pohqw/public_html/projects/myapp/add_product.php on line 10
> {"success":true}

Seems your warning gets thrown out along with your `{"success":true}`

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing the line

```
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(AddFragment.this.getActivity());
```

with

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```